# Меняю бранч, а комитит попрежнему в транк

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Работаю с использованием git-svn.
После выгрузки проекта меняю делаю checkout тега, но dcommit происходит в транк. Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Comment: Чтобы это исправить, нужно выполнить вот эту команду.

Comment: В теги обычно не коммитят, ни в Git, ни в Subversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось, что проблема была в git. В последующей версии было исправлено.